# Weekview titleFormat

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have the following config:

```
views: {
            week: {
                titleFormat: { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'},
                dayHeaderContent: (args) => {
                    return moment(args.date).format('dddd Do')
                },
            }
        },
```

..which is displaying the headerTitle of the week view as 10/23/2022 – 10/29/2022. How can i change the format so that is 23/10/2022 - 29/10/2022 (from m/d/y to d/m/y). Previous answers do not refer to v5 and it's newer titleFormat strings.

Comment: A top-level `titleFormat: 'D/MM/YYYY'`, outside `views.week` works fine. Do you specifically want a custom format for each different view?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Added that outside of the views config, and now have this message in my console: "Uncaught TypeError: context.cmdFormatter is not a function", and the calendar does not render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example below.

[The `titleFormat` docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/titleFormat) show that it accepts a "Date Formatter".  Following the link for that, and scrolling down to [the Formatting Strings section](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting#formatting-strings) , we see you can use normal Moment formatting strings, if you have the Moment plugin installed/enabled.  [The linked docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/moment-plugin) describe how to install the Moment plugin with script tags as I've used below, but also cover using npm or webpack, if that's what you have.

OK now Moment is enabled, back to the page about date formatting, there's a link to the Moment docs about its [date formatting strings](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/), and we can see how to construct format you're after: `D/MM/YYYY`.

And now we can just slot that into your week-specific view, as described in [the view-specific options docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-specific-options) linked from the initial [`titleFormat` page](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/titleFormat):

```
views: {
    week: {
        titleFormat: "D/MM/YYYY"
    }
}
```

Working snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridWeek',
        views: {
            week: {
                titleFormat: "D/MM/YYYY"
            }
        }
    });
    calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.3/main.min.css">
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.27.0/min/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.3/main.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/moment@5.5.0/main.global.min.js'></script>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: Yes that works perfectly, thanks. I had moment installed, but not the fullcalendar <-> moment bridge. All working as explained now, thank you for the detailed explanation.